# A finite sum closely related to the binomial series

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-theorem

After integrating a certain function in terms of the binomial theorem I was left with a finite sum
that I haven't made any progress on yet.

$$ \sum_{k=0}^{2n} \frac{(2n)!}{k!(2n-k)!}  \frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1} $$

The limit is always an even number.  Any help summing this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not a proof, but Mathematica evaluates this to be $\frac{(2n)!\sqrt{\pi}}{2\left(2n+\frac{1}{2}\right)!}$, I believe using the factorial in the denominator as the gamma function of the argument plus 1. Hopefully having a closed form is helpful for coming up with a proof.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is another variation based upon the *[Beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function)*.

> We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{k=0}^{2n}}\color{blue}{\frac{(2n)!}{k!(2n-k)!}  \frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}}
> &=\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\binom{2n}{k}(-1)^k\int_{0}^1x^{2k}\,dz\tag{1}\\
> &=\int_{0}^1\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\binom{2n}{k}\left(-z^2\right)^k\,dz\\
> &=\int_{0}^1\left(1-z^2\right)^{2n}\,dz\\
> &=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^1\left(1-z^2\right)^{2n}\,dz\tag{2}\\
> &=2^{4n-1}\int_{-1}^1\left(\frac{1+z}{2}\right)^{2n}\left(1-\frac{1+z}{2}\right)^{2n}\,dz\tag{3}\\
> &=2^{4n}\int_{0}^1u^{2n}(1-u)^{2n}\,du\tag{4}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{2^{4n}}{4n+1}\binom{4n}{2n}^{-1}}\tag{5}
> \end{align*}

Note that we have $\frac{2^{4n}}{4n+1}\binom{4n}{2n}^{-1}=\frac{2^{4n+1}}{2n+1}\binom{4n+2}{2n+1}^{-1}$ in accordance with @MarkoRiedel's answer.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we use $\frac{1}{k+1}=\int_{0}^1z^k\,dz$.
- In (2) we use that the even function $f(z)=(1-z^2)^{2n}$ is symmetric with respect to the $y$-axis.
- In (3) we use $1-z^2=(1+z)(1-z)=\frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{1+z}{2}\right)\left(1-\frac{1+z}{2}\right)$.
- In (4) we substitute $u=\frac{1+z}{2}, du=\frac{1}{2}dz$.
- In (5) we we write the reciprocal of a binomial coefficient using the *[beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function)*
  \begin{align*}
  \binom{n}{k}^{-1}=(n+1)\int_0^1z^k(1-z)^{n-k}\,dz
  \end{align*}

Comment: Verified. (+1).

Answer (score 6):

The basic technique which has appeared several times at MSE is to
introduce the function

$$f(z) = \frac{(2n)!}{2z+1} \prod_{q=0}^{2n} \frac{1}{z-q}$$

which has the property that for $0 \le k\le 2n$

$$\mathrm{Res}_{z=k} f(z) =
\frac{(2n)!}{2k+1}
\prod_{q=0}^{k-1} \frac{1}{k-q}
\prod_{q=k+1}^{2n} \frac{1}{k-q}
\\ = \frac{(2n)!}{2k+1}
\frac{1}{k!} \frac{(-1)^{2n-k}}{(2n-k)!}
= {2n\choose k} \frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}.$$

With residues summing to zero and the residue at infinity being zero by
inspection we thus have

$$\sum_{k=0}^{2n}  {2n\choose k} \frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}
= - \mathrm{Res}_{z=-1/2} f(z).$$

This is

$$- \frac{1}{2} (2n)!
\prod_{q=0}^{2n} \frac{1}{-1/2 - q}
= -\frac{1}{2} (2n)! 2^{2n+1} (-1)^{2n+1}
\prod_{q=0}^{2n} \frac{1}{2q+1}
\\ = (2n)! 2^{2n} \frac{(2n+1)! 2^{2n+1}}{(4n+2)!}.$$

We get at last

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\frac{2^{4n+1}}{2n+1} {4n+2\choose 2n+1}^{-1} .}$$

Comment: Great! Your answer can nicely be used as reference for this technique. (+1)

Comment: Thanks! You have the more compact expression. There is a typo where you quote my result.

Comment: Thanks! Typo corrected.

Comment: Additional readings: [Wikipedia on Norlund-Rice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%B8rlund%E2%80%93Rice_integral).

Comment: Thanks again, Marko. Interesting reference.

Answer (score 2):

In terms of the Gamma function, your sum can be written as

$$ \dfrac{(2n)!\; \Gamma(3/2)}{\Gamma(2n+3/2)}$$
(the $\sqrt{\pi}/2$ in zjs's comment is $\Gamma(3/2)$).